# Can I rotate the instrument bar in photoshop ?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Can I rotate the instrument bar in photoshop CS5 and display it horizontally ?

I mean this:

[image: toolbar]

Answer (score 1):

No. I think you can only have either one or two columns of tools.

Feel free to suggest it to Adobe for CS6, however.